# AngularJS javascript function gets stuck inside an else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code whereby i want to check if code input data is the same in the local db.  This code works fine until it gets to where i have marked as **code hangs or stops here**. Once the code gets to the condition it runs perfectly and assigns notifier  to be true but it doesnt come out of that function  and is stuck there hence the remaining part of the code is not executed. Can anyone explain to me why ? I am building an Ionic, AngularJS app.

```
function checklocalDB(localdb, result) {
    var d= $q.defer();
    var identifier = false;
    var notifier = false;
        // var f = function(localdb, result){
    if(localdb === false) {
        console.log("inside localdb false")
        var insert_into_table = "INSERT INTO preferences(description, value) VALUES ('username','" + result[0].username + "'), ('token','" + result[0].token.toString() + "')";

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insert_into_table).then(function (res) {
            console.log("executedd")
            var updateDB = "UPDATE preferences SET value='true' WHERE description='registered'";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, updateDB).then(function (res) {
                console.log("executed")
                identifier = true;
                notifier = true;
                //d.resolve(identifier)
                var query = "SELECT id, description, value FROM preferences";
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res) {
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            }, function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("inside localdb true")
        var dbNew = null;
        var query = "SELECT id, description, value FROM preferences";
        console.log(localdb)
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res) {
            console.log("hhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
            console.log(res.rows.item(2).value)
            console.log(result[0].username)
            if(res.rows.item(2).value != result[0].username) {
                console.log("username different")
                $cordovaSQLite.deleteDB("loanstreet_partners.db");
                dbNew = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("loanstreet_partners.db");
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(dbNew, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preferences (id integer primary key, description string, value string)").then(function (res) {
                    console.log("done")
                    var insert_into_table = "INSERT INTO preferences (description, value) SELECT 'registered' as registered, 'false' as value UNION SELECT 'logged_in', 'false'";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insert_into_table).then(function (res) {
                        console.log("1st")
                        var insert_into_table = "INSERT INTO preferences(description, value) VALUES ('username','" + result[0].username + "'), ('token','" + result[0].token.toString() + "')";
                        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insert_into_table).then(function (res) {
                            console.log("2nd")
                            identifier = true;
                            notifier = true;

                            var updateDB = "UPDATE preferences SET value='true' WHERE description='registered'";
                            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, updateDB).then(function (res) {
                            }, function (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                            });
                        });
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                }, function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            }
            else {
                notifier = true;
                console.log("im here")
                return notifier;
                // ***code hangs or stops here***
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }  

    // ***this is never executed because it still remains false*** 
    if(notifier === true) {
        console.log(identifier)
        console.log(notifier)
        d.resolve(identifier) 
    }

    return d.promise;
        // watch identifier when value change then only resolve
        //d.resolve(identifier)
        //return d.promise; 
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You need to look into `asynchronous` programming.  `notifier` will always be `false` when the line `if (notifier === true)` is executed, as the asynchronous handlers above will not have executed by then.

Comment: @alex actually tht is not where my error is because i have taken care of tht. d error is where i put d remain code hangs or stops here

Comment: put the line `console.log('notifier:', notifier);` immediately below your `***this is never executed because it still remains false***` comment.  I'm sure you will see it in the console (or an `Error` that is thrown beforehand).